# why does div continue to occupy 100% of the parent even if it has explicit width of 50%

Tags: css

I have two divs inside their parent div:

```
<div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>

.col-1, .col-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

They both have width of 50%. Yet they continue to occupy 100% of their parent even though their background is indeed 50% of the parent. Why so?

Comment: They don't. As block level element they're placed in different lines. You probably need to `float` them to a side.

Comment: @HashemQolami, thanks. Yeah, I know how to put them in one line with float. My question is about this _A div needs to be thought of as a division which, unless you tell it to float, will take all the width of a line, even though it may not fill it_. Can you elaborate on that? Maybe point to some info source? What property allows a div to take all the width?

Comment: HTML 4.01 Spec [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline): `By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not [...]`.

Comment: @HashemQolami, got it, thanks! So probably as `Juan - devtopia.coop` noted it's the `display:block` that makes it behave in this way regardless of the `width` property.

Answer (score 3):

A div needs to be thought of as a *division* which, unless you tell it to float, will take **all the width of a line**, even though it **may not fill** it, this is because of the inherent css property `display:block` that's applied to a div. If you tell both divs to float by adding `float:left;` or `float:right;` to their css, they will allow other elements to share the width of their parent. Here's a snippet (you can see the result by clicking on the run button) of what it will look like

```css
#container .child{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.red{background:red;}
.blue{background:blue}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='child red'>a</div>
  <div class='child blue'>b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know how to put them in one line with float. My question is about this _A div needs to be thought of as a division which, unless you tell it to float, will take all the width of a line, even though it may not fill it._. Can you elaborate on that? Maybe point to some info source? What propery does allow a div to take all the width?

Comment: I'd say that its inherent display:block property, makes it take all width

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.col-1{
  float:left;
}
.col-2{
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also experiment with the display property, for example `display:inline-block` could help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Example program... You can use "float"

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">

<div id="menu" style="background-color:blue; height:200px; width:50%; float:left; color:white;">
Div1</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:50%;float:left;">
Div2</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to precisely control the position of a `<div>`, you should use `position: absolute`

```
<style>
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  .col-1, .col-2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
  }
  .col-1 { left: 0; }
  .col-2 { left: 50%; }
</style>

[...]

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1">[...]</div>
  <div class="col-2">[...]</div>
</div>
```